# string_comparator in C

Tags: c, comparator, cstring, qsort

Okay so I need to several quite long strings in C. So I say to myself "why, you'd better use that handy dandy qsort function! Better write yourself a string_comparator for it!"

So of course I do and here she is:

```
int string_comparator(const void* el1, const void* el2) {

char* x = (char*) el1;
char* y = (char*) el2;

int str_len = strlen(x);
int i = 0;
for (; i < str_len; i++) {

    //when there are non-equal chars
    if (x[i] != y[i]) {
        break;
    }
}

return x[i] - y[i];
}
```

So of course I pass my handy dandy string_comparator function to the C qsort function as such:

```
qsort(list.words, list.num_words, sizeof(char*), string_comparator);
```

list is a struct that holds a char** (words) and ints which refer to the number of words held by it (such as num_words)

Now I have the problem where my list is not getting sorted alphabetically like I had hoped! I put a bunch of printf statements in my comparator and it printed out garbage values for the strings every time so I'm fairly sure that is the problem. But why is that the problem?? I've used qsort before (never to sort words..just sorting characters) and from what I understand this should work...What's going wrong here?

I appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common mistake when using `qsort()`.  Here are the corrections:

```
char *x = *(char **) el1;
char *y = *(char **) el2;
```

Because `list.words` has type `char **`, not type `char *`, right?

### Another example of `qsort()`

Here's how you sort an array of `int` with `qsort()`:

```
int int_comparator(const void *el1, const void *el2)
{
    int x = *(int *) el1;
    int y = *(int *) el2;
    return x - y;
}

void sort_ints(int *a, size_t n)
{
    // these two lines are both "correct"
    // the second line is more "obviously correct"

    // qsort(a, n, sizeof(int), int_comparator);
    qsort(a, n, sizeof(*a), int_comparator);
}
```

Now, if you go through and replace `int` with `char *`, you have to replace `int *` with `char **`.

Comment: yeah it does...so it passes in a pointer to the entire list? at a certain address?

Comment: the comparator function. it seems that it is having a char** passed into it?

What's the reason behind that syntax?

Comment: @Ethan: The comparison function has two parameters.  The parameters are pointers to elements in your array.  Your elements are `char *`.  You do not have `char` in your array.  See example with `int`.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH. DUh!! Because it's taking a pointer...geeze. THanks! I'll accept as the answer in 7 mins when I'm allowed to

Comment: @Ethan list.words is most likely an array of pointers, such as `const char* words [N] = { "hello", "world", ... };`. Since qsort expects a pointer, the array decays into a pointer to its first element when passed to qsort.